# Alternative definition for order-embedding

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

I realize that the traditional definition for an order-embedding f is that

$a_1 \sqsubseteq a_2 \iff f(a_1) \sqsubseteq f(a_2)$

However, is it also fair to say that if $(A, \sqsubseteq)$ is a lattice, a definition for meet and this partial-order uniquely define one another:

$a_1 \sqsubseteq a_2 \iff a_1 \sqcap a_2 = a_1$

And so an alternative/equivalent way of saying f is an order-embedding might be:

$f(a_1 \sqcap a_2) = f(a_1) \sqcap f(a_2)$

Thank you! Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embeddings are functions from one structure to another which preserve the structure (and do no add additional structure to the image either).

For partially ordered sets this means, as you suggest that $a\sqsubseteq b\iff f(a)\sqsubseteq f(b)$. Lattices have *more* structure, so we can expect embeddings of lattices to preserve that structure. But note that this requires additional and explicit statements.

Consider the lattices $\mathcal P(X)$ and $\mathcal P(Y)$ ordered by inclusion, where $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{1,2,3,4\}$. Now define $f\colon\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(Y)$:
$$\begin{align} &f(\varnothing)=\varnothing\\ &f(\{1\})=\{1,4\}\\ &f(\{2\})=\{2,4\}\\ &f(\{1,2\})=\{1,2,3,4\}\end{align}$$

It is easy to see why $f$ is an order embedding, but the lattice structure is all skewered. $\{1\}\cap\{2\}=\varnothing$ but $f(\{1\})\cap f(\{2\})=\{4\}\neq f(\varnothing)$.

So while we can define a lattice structure on $\operatorname{Range}(f)$, this is not the structure inherited from the structure on $\mathcal P(Y)$, so in some sense it's cheating.

**To sum up** remember the motto, if you want more, assume more.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I have not been careful enough.

Comment: Is there a term to use for my second definition (preserves meet, embeds meet)? You are saying that my second definition implies that f is an order-embedding, but is a stronger statement and goes further than simply saying it is an order embedding?

Comment: If you read a bit about Boolean algebras, in particular complete Boolean algebras, you'll quickly learn that these examples are abundant, and that there's is a difference between requiring that the subalgebra agree on the completions, or the maximal and minimal elements, and so on.

Comment: And yes, since the order itself is definable from the join/meet operations, respecting those would necessarily mean respecting anything definable from them, and in particular the order. (Recall that in a lattice you also have joins, not just meets.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was able to prove the latter for a function f and somewhat carelessly said it was an order-embedding. Thankfully this is a stronger property and I should only need to tweak my explanation. Your example was very helpful in clarifying this for me!

Comment: You're most welcome!